# Why adding geometry package with specific values affects how breqn package typesets math?

Tags: spacing, labels, typography, breqn

Should using `geometry` package with some specific values affect how `breqn` math is typeset? In the following I see two major differences in math when add `geometry`.

Comparing the following two examples, all using lualatex on Texlive 2022

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage[letterpaper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
%            left=0.9in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
%            footskip=.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dgroup*}
\begin{dmath*}
\int \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x} = \int M\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} 
\end{dmath*}
\begin{dmath*}
\int \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x} = \int \ln \left(\frac{y +x}{x +3}\right)-\frac{y +x}{x +3}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} 
\end{dmath*}
\begin{dmath}[number=3]
\phi = \left(3-y \right) \ln \left(\frac{-3+y}{x +3}\right)+\left(y +x \right) \ln \left(\frac{y +x}{x +3}\right)+\left(3-y \right) \ln \left(x +3\right)-x+ f(y)  
\end{dmath}
\end{dgroup*}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

When uncommenting the code above which uses `geometry` package, this is now the output

[image]

The question is : is this to be expected? How is one to know before hand if changing some of geometry parameters/values will cause math to come out worst than before?

Should not this be automatically handled by breqn regardless of what values are used for geometry?

in addition to the label problem, in the first example alignment is not on the `=` even though `dgroup` is used for all equations. I expected both examples to be aligned on `=` but it seems `geometry` spacing used affects how `breqn` typeset things?

Notice that the second example has the correct alignment on `=` for all equations.

Comment: If you change the layout of the page, different output is expected. Probably you hit some threshold. I wonder a bit what output you expect.

Comment: **I wonder a bit what output you expect.** I expect at least the equations to remain aligned at `=`. Isn't this wahat the use of `dgroup` supposed to mean? I also expect the label at the end not to be so close to the math.

Comment: would need to trace this example but the answer to the general question in the title is obviously "yes". breqn is all about linebreaking so if you change the line width it changes every calculation it does

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok. Lets forget about the label being too close to the end of the equation. How about the equations being aligned at `=`? I thought this is what `dgroup` is supposed to do. But may be I misunderstood what `dgroup` main purpose is?  I would at least expect the equations to remain aligned at `=` when changing the page width.

Comment: shrug, breqn is explicitly documented as being experimental. Both of your images show cases where for some reason it can not find a break in the last line so falls back on sub-optimal alternatves in one case it gave up alignment and moved it left, in the second it just managed to squeeze it in, but bumping up to the equation number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is `framesep={20pt}` into `\begin{dmath}[number=3,framesep={20pt}]` also when there is recalled `geometry` package. You can observe that the label **(3)** it is not close with the formula. See the screenshot.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
           left=0.9in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
           footskip=.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dgroup*}
\begin{dmath*}
\int \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x} = \int M\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} 
\end{dmath*}
\begin{dmath*}
\int \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x} = \int \ln \left(\frac{y +x}{x +3}\right)-\frac{y +x}{x +3}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} 
\end{dmath*}
\begin{dmath}[number=3,framesep={20pt}]
\phi = \left(3-y \right) \ln \left(\frac{-3+y}{x +3}\right)+
\left(y +x \right) \ln \left(\frac{y +x}{x +3}\right)+  \left(3-y \right) \ln \left(x +3\right)-x+ f(y)  
\end{dmath}
\end{dgroup*}
\end{document}
```

[image]